# How to make a command on a discord bot to randomly generate a quote?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, dice

I'm coding my own discord bot and in a nutshell I need some help with the code.
I would need my bot to pick a random response (1/10 for example) when I use a command like !roll or !dice, and once used, a user cool down of 6 days to be added (i.e the command can't be used by said user for 6 days afterwards, and would respond with the days, hours and minutes)

I'm pretty new to code, but I figured out some

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js")
const Bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = "my token"
Bot.login('my token');

Bot.on('message' , function (message){
if(message.content == '!roll')
var roll =(Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+1);
   if (roll = 1 )
    {message.reply('Wowza!');
}
        else {message.reply('lol!');
    }
```

whenever i roll, the bot displays either one of the outputs, then the other, and then spams the two till it is shut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a single `=` in a comparison statement such as an `if`. A single equals is an assignment operator which means when you write `roll = 1`, you are **setting roll to 1** instead of checking if the value it holds is 1.

Always use `==` or `===` when doing comparison statements.  So, you would want to use `roll == 1` or `roll === 1`.

[Here's a good article about double equals vs triple equals in JavaScript](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)

```
if (roll == 1 ) {
    message.reply('Wowza!');
}
else {
    message.reply('lol!');
}
```

Also, after looking further at your code, you have some more issues. You want to wrap the first `if` in a set of curly braces since it should encompass the following lines of code.

```
Bot.on('message' , function (message){
    if (message.content == '!roll') 
    {
        var roll =(Math.floor(Math.random()*200)+1);
        if (roll == 1)
        {
            message.reply('Wowza!');
        }
        else 
        {
            message.reply('lol!');
        }
    }
}
```